# How to copy Krita brushes?

Tags: krita

I found several good brushes in Krita default pack, so how can i copy them, because I want to use them on other computer and dont find them every time, and just use from flash-card or something similar? And how can I copy all Krita brushes?

When I trying to ind brushes in file manager with their name, there are no brushes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Krita's default brushes are stored in bundles which are located at C:\Program Files\Krita (x64)\share\krita\bundles (in Windows). The file extension is .bundle - but the file itself is actually just a regular zip file.

You can copy the .bundle file, and paste it onto your desktop, or somewhere you can find it easily. Then change the file extension to .zip - open it, and in there you will find all the brushes in the folder called "brushes".

Comment: I found all besid one: "j)_WaterC_Spread_WideArea". Where I can find this?

Comment: @user99579 - I don't know, perhaps it's in another shared brush/bundles folder. There are several locations. Try C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\krita and C:\Program Files\Krita (x64)\share\krita

Comment: Thanks, found this in "...Krita (x64)\share\krita\paintoppresets"